# Redirecting bash stdout/stderr to two places?

Tags: bash, redirect

This one's been bugging me for a while now. Is it possible to redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to both the terminal output *and* to a program?

I understand it's possible to redirect the outputs to a file and to `stdout` with [`tee`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee), but I want it to go to a program (my editor [TextMate]) as well as to the terminal output… surely this is possible (I know its possible with zsh…)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/60955/1295595

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use a named pipe, which is intended for exactly the situation you describe.

```
mkfifo some_pipe
command_that_writes_to_stdout | tee some_pipe \
  & command_that_reads_from_stdin < some_pipe
rm some_pipe
```

Or, in Bash:

```
command_that_writes_to_stdout | tee >(command_that_reads_from_stdin)
```

Comment: Bash's process substitution will do this for you in one step (sort of an "anonymous named pipe")
  command_that_writes_to_stdout | tee >(command_that_reads_from_stdin)

Comment: That's only stdout not stderr.

Comment: @Nils: if you replace `|` with `|&` then bash redirects both stdout/stderr.

Answer (score 21):

> Is it possible to redirect stdout and stderr to both the terminal output and to a program?

I'm not sure how useful it is to combine stdout and stderr on the input to an editor, but does omething like this do what you need?

```
input_prog 2>&1 | tee /dev/tty | my_editor
```

Comment: Charles, is that "tee >/dev/tty" correct? I've never seen it done that way. I would usually just "tee /dev/tty" to get the effect you're after.

Comment: @Pax @Charles Bailey fixed typo. Rollback if tee> was intended

Comment: Doh, yes, sorry. Obviously stdout can't be redirected and piped at the same time. Thanks.

Comment: At least on Linux, you can also tee to `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr`

Answer (score 2):

I don't actually know whether TextMate can take a file to edit as its standard input, that seems a little bizarre. I suspect you would want to send the stdout/stderr to a file and edit it there, in which case you need:

```
progname 2>&1 | tee tempfile ; textmate tempfile
```

The `2>&1` redirects `stderr` (file handle 2) to go to the same place as `stdout` (file handle 1) so that both of them end up in a single stream. The `tee` command then writes that to `tempfile` as well as `stdout`.

Then, once the process has finished, the editor is called up on the temporary file.

If it can accept standard input for editing, use:

```
progname 2>&1 | tee /dev/tty | textmate
```

Comment: Pipe anything to mate and it'll open in a new document