# Can grep show count and matches at the same time?

Tags: grep

I've search the web for this but couldn't find the solution I wanted.

I used grep to search for lines having the word **one** and that works fine.

I want grep to also count the matched lines as well. But I only get the number only.

I tried this but no cigar.

```
grep -cn 'one' foo 
2
```

Option c is to count and option n is to show lines. But it still shows the count only.

Thus far, this is the only way to do it. Running grep twice :(

```
grep  'one' foo ; grep  'one' foo  | wc -l
one two three
seven one blah
2
```

Is it possible for grep to show both the matches and the count without repeating the command again?

BTW, I know awk can do this as I've seen in my research. But I want to know if grep can do this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `grep  'one' foo | tee >(wc -l) ` or `grep  'one' foo | tee /dev/tty | wc -l` would work  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670784/redirecting-bash-stdout-stderr-to-two-places and https://superuser.com/questions/7448/can-the-output-of-one-command-be-piped-to-two-other-commands

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670784/redirecting-bash-stdout-stderr-to-two-places

Comment: WOW! It works!!! Thanks Jerry Jeremiah!!! You're awesome!!!

Comment: @noob2021 you know that's not `grep` outputing the count, right? The answer to your question of "Can grep show count and matches at the same time?" is simply `no`.