# Piping a file through tail and head via tee

Tags: bash, shell, tee

Starting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624669/unix-head-and-tail-of-file/16637719?noredirect=1#comment23935309_16637719) I tried to read a file and emit the head and the tail of the file (reading the file only once).

I tried the following:
`tee >(head) >(tail) > /dev/null < text.txt`

This line works as expected, but I'd like to get rid of the /dev/null. So I tried:
`tee >(head) | tail < text.txt`

But this line does not work as expected (well, as I expected), it prints the head but does not return after that. Apparently tail is waiting for something. But I don't know what for exactly.
I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748770/broken-pipe-in-tee-with-process-substituion), but I could not get it running with the given answers.

Answer (score 5):

In `tee >(head) | tail < text.txt`, the text file goes directly to `tail`. You probably meant

```
tee >(head) < text.txt | tail
```

Which does not wait for anything, but does not work either, because the output of both tee and head go to tail.

Redirecting the head's output to a new file descriptor and then taking it back works, but I am not sure it is "cleaner" than using /dev/null:

```
( tee >(head >&3) < text.txt | tail) 3>&1
```

Comment: I don't think the output of `head` is affected by the pipe, only the output of `tee`.

Comment: @chepner: I created a file with numbers 1..100, then tried `tee >(head -n 3) < text.txt | tail`.

Comment: @chepner You're mistaken. Compare the result of `echo -e "a\nb\nc" | tee >(head -1) | tail -1` to the result of `echo -e "a\nb\nc" | tee >(head -2) | tail -1`.

Comment: I get `a\nc\n` vs `a\nb\n\c`, which is what I would expect if both `head` and `tail` received the same input stream.

Comment: @chepner: What version of bash are you running? I am getting `a` and `b`.

Comment: Mea culpa. I've been testing with `zsh`, which raises its own set of (off-topic) questions :)

Comment: Wow, I would never thought about it. But it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe an interesting observation: using zsh the output is apparently concurrent (alternating lines from tail and head), while it's not on my bash.

Comment: Oh gosh. No it does not work.

To see how concurrent the shells are, I created a file with 1M lines (75MB). Now the command does not work as expected anymore (tail emits lines around 15k).

Does the pipe gets closed to early? Any ideas?

Comment: @Bouncner: I do not understand it. If I replace `head` with `sed -n 1,10p` or `tac | tail | tac`, it works... :-O

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16664257/1030675 for a follow-up.