# Misbehaving head with redirection

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection, tee

In a reply to [Piping a file through tail and head via tee](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16657209/1030675), a strange behaviour of `head` has been observed in the following construct when working with huge files:

```
#! /bin/bash
for i in {1..1000000} ; do echo $i ; done > /tmp/n

( tee >(sed -n '1,3p'        >&3 ) < /tmp/n | tail -n2 ) 3>&1 # Correct
echo '#'
( tee >(tac | tail -n3 | tac >&3 ) < /tmp/n | tail -n2 ) 3>&1 # Correct
echo '#'
( tee >(head -n3             >&3 ) < /tmp/n | tail -n2 ) 3>&1 # Not correct!?
```

#### Output:

```
1
2
3
999999
1000000
#
1
2
3
999999
1000000
#
1
2
3
15504
15
```

#### Question:

Why does not the last line output the same lines as the previous two lines?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `head` exits as soon as it transfers three first lines. Subsequently, `tee` gets killed with SIGPIPE because the reading end of the "FILE" pipe it is writing to is closed, but not until it manages to output some lines to its stdout.

If you execute just this:

```
tee >(head -n3 >/dev/null) < /tmp/n
```

You will see what happens better.

OTOH, `tac` reads the whole file as it has to reverse it, as does `sed`, probably to be consistent.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. I can even add `cat` like this `( tee >(head -n3 >&3; cat > /dev/null ) < /tmp/n | tail -n2 ) 3>&1` to make it work.

Comment: You're welcome :) Although, I'd say using `sed` for that part would be clearer.

Comment: Note that for files smaller than 5 lines at least some of them will get output twice.