# Is there a workaround for this Broken Pipe error?

Tags: bash, pipe

When I run the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '[:graph:]' | head -c 64
```

(which is supposed to print 64 random characters and it does)

I get the following output:

```
Kn5Thh'H]F2NMG3^2(T*GdH]C+|Y0uj%C?LGFo=9d9o%vcP9k~6u~Q&exr`RuQv{./myScript: line 2: 21677 Broken Pipe             cat /dev/urandom
     21678                       | tr -dc '[:graph:]'
     21679 Done                    | head -c 64
```

Why am I getting the `Broken Pipe` error? Is it because `cat` doesn't finish printing but `head` is already done, so it sends a `SIGPIPE`?

How do I avoid this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664257/misbehaving-head-with-redirection

Comment: Why do you use a *useless cat* in the first place?

Comment: As a work-around, use `2>/dev/null` redirection.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/a/554896/513541

Comment: Potentially useful as well: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77242/117549

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, this behavior seems to depend on two settings:

1. compile-time option `DONT_REPORT_SIGPIPE` hasn't been set in your bash version (cf config-top.h)
2. bash option `set -o pipefail` is in effect in your environment

Nonetheless, you can create a subshell with parentheses, and redirect the standard-error of the subshell into /dev/null:

```
(tr -dc '[[:graph:]]' </dev/urandom | head -c64) 2>/dev/null
```

--- Before the last edit this answer looked like this: ---

```
tr -dc '[[:graph:]]' </dev/urandom 2>/dev/null | head -c64
```

Comment: I kind of doubt it, but edited my answer and added another version.

Comment: Ok, examined the problem, seems like you have two unusual (but perfectly valid/legal) settings in effect.

Answer (score 4):

You do not actually need a `pipe` in the first place and you do not need to use `cat` to print the output of `/dev/urandom` this is a very bad habit to spawn unnecessary processes and waste cycles.

The following command works fine (**bash**):

```
head -c64 <(tr -dc '[[:graph:]]' < /dev/urandom)
```

**output:**

```
$ head -c64 <(tr -dc '[[:graph:]]' < /dev/urandom)
\|_)gk$,gIW%vvBcc~B~:N2*FwozcdomgUI~I9$r$9Wj`q$KT4IoNI`)SS-i"Sc^

$ head -c64 <(tr -dc '[[:graph:]]' < /dev/urandom)                                                                                             
T8j0,?L))L4n@|(*EJ>Nkd|c7^t'[-7rnq8;E!sxIc>;SwOIhiPY"Zp}QWH&95nC
```

**READINGS:**

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-badunixhabits.html#ten
https://www.infoworld.com/article/2614499/unix/unix--when-pipes-don-t-make-sense.html
https://superuser.com/questions/1059781/what-exactly-is-in-bash-and-in-zsh
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

For **other shells** use:

```
tr -dc '[[:graph:]]' </dev/urandom | head -c64
```

Comment: How about using a non bash-only variation: `tr -dc '[[:graph:]]' </dev/urandom | head -c64`

Comment: thank you for your insight!!! :) I have edited the post to take into account other shells

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise I could ditch `cat` altogether... However, using `head -c64 <(tr -dc '[:graph:]' < /dev/urandom)` still results in a `Broken Pipe` error...

Answer (score 1):

Your diagnosis of the cause of the problem is correct, and one easy workaround is to use sed instead of head: `sed -n "1,10p"` is equivalent to `head -n10`. Or in your particular case, this will match and print the first 64 characters from the standard input:

```
sed -rn "1s/(.{64}).*/\1/p"
```

`-r` is a Gnu extension.  Without it, it looks more complicated but it's just because the special characters must be escaped:

```
sed -n "1s/\(.\{64\}\).*/\1/p"
```

Different systems may require a different quote character, e.g. ' instead of ".