# Why piping truncates content, while redirecting to/from intermediary file doesn't?

Tags: bash, macos

I'm seeing my content truncated when using pipe in a sequence like:

```
jq ... |
jq ... |
tee tee_file |
jq ... |

# content gets truncated here

head ... | sed ... | awk ... | awk ... | sed
```

...but everything works fine if I redirect output to intermediary file, then immediately feed that file to the downstream processes:

```
jq ... |
jq ... |
tee some_file |
jq ... > intermediary_file

# content remains intact here

cat intermediary_file |
head ... | sed ... | awk ... | awk ... | sed
```

The `tee_file` is not used as input in the downstream part of the above piping sequence, only in some later commands.

Using `--unbuffered` in `jq` doesn't help.

**What are the reasons for such difference in behaviour, and how can I fix it?**

---

MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G5019)
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16664257/1030675

Comment: @choroba Could you elaborate how exactly is my problem similar to the linked question?

Comment: It's caused by `head` terminating after having successfully written the expected amount of data.

Comment: Hm, in my case the content gets truncated BEFORE `head` even starts, I double-checked that.

Comment: Try using `sed` or `tac` + `tail` as shown in the linked question instead of `head`. If it helps, the problem is the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "content"? What's being truncated? Are you talking about the data in `tee_file`? The output to the terminal? Data passed in the pipe?

Comment: @thatotherguy The output of the last JQ preceding the comment gets truncated when sent as input to the HEAD immediately following the comment.

Comment: without a tiny set of sample data that illustrates your problem, we are only guessing. If the `head` thing isn't your problem, its something else in your code, not in the utilities you are calling ;-) . right? Good luck!

Comment: @choroba Surprisingly, it works. Do I undestand correctly that `sed -n 'p'` is the easiest/safest way to send input to output as it is?

Comment: `"The output of the last JQ preceding the comment"` Do you really have a comment embedded inline with a bunch of pipes? That won't work. Your code must be `jq ... |
jq ... |
tee some_file |
jq ... |
head ... | sed ... | awk ... | awk ... | sed` . Good luck.

Comment: @wassrubleff: `cat` is probably even simpler and faster.

Comment: @choroba That's the problem: `cat` didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @wassrubleff The purpose of `head` is to truncate the stream and stop the input pipe. How would you be able to tell the difference between `jq` output being truncated *before* `head`, and `jq` output being truncated *by* `head`? If you can post a MCVE, that would make everything much easier.

Comment: Earlier you said that "the content gets truncated BEFORE head even starts". Are you assuming that in your code, first `jq` runs, then another `jq` runs, then `tee` runs, etc? This is not true. All the elements run in parallel. If the last `sed` stops immediately, then the first `jq` will stop immediately. This is just like a water pipe, where plugging the output end will immediately stop water from entering the inlet.

Comment: As an aside, any logical structure that involves `sed ... | awk ... | awk ... | sed` is an almost certainly offense against man and God and should be taken out and shot.