# Piping standard output of tee effects output of its files

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection

I came across the answer to [How can I send the stdout of one process to multiple processes using (preferably unnamed) pipes in Unix (or Windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60942/how-can-i-send-the-stdout-of-one-process-to-multiple-processes-using-preferably) and was playing around with `grep` when I noticed a strange issue.  The following works as I'd expect:

```
$ while [ 1 ]; do sleep 1 ; echo tick; done | tee >(grep -o ti) >(grep -o ic) >(grep tick) >/dev/null
ic
ti
tick
ic
tick
ti
^C
```

All three `grep` commands are applied to the output of the loop.

However, if I pipe the output of `tee` into a grep (instead of redirecting it to /dev/null), the `grep`s on the files stop working:

```
$ while [ 1 ]; do sleep 1 ; echo tick; done | tee >(grep -o ti) >(grep -o ic) | grep tick
tick
tick
^C
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll hazard a guess...

```
tee >(grep -o ti) >(grep -o ic) >(grep tick) >/dev/null
tee >(grep -o ti) >(grep -o ic) | grep tick
```

In the first command, the arguments are processed left-to-right, so `grep -o ti` has its output going to standard output, and so do the other two process substitutions, and then the standard output of `tee` is redirected to `/dev/null` (but the processes are already launched with the original standard output).

In the second command, the pipe to `grep tick` is already set up before the shell works on `>(grep -o ti)`, so the standard output of the `grep` goes down the pipe.  The `ti` and `ic` lines are not selected by the `grep tick` command.  If you changed that to `grep i`, you'd probably see the `ti` and `ic` lines too.

I had to adjust the command to:

```
while true; do echo tick; done |
tee >(grep -o ti) >(grep -o ic) | grep i | grep -v tick
```

to see the `ti` and `ic` commands.  This is related to buffering with standard I/O; the output from the `grep` commands is going to a pipe, so it is fully buffered, and the outputs appear in batches.  Unless I dropped the `sleep 1`, it would have taken far too long to see the alternative outputs.

A still better command for viewing the output was:

```
while true; do echo tick; done |
tee >(grep -o ti) >(grep -o ic) | grep i | uniq
```

The output contained lines like:

```
ictick
tick
ic
i
ti
tick
ic
tick
ti
ttick
ic
itick
tick
ic
i
ti
tiic
ictick
tick
```

The moral of the story is probably to ensure that the outputs of each process substitution go to a known file.

Comment: so, to be clear, the output of the loop and the output of the two greps inside the file redirections are all going into the `grep tick`?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be what is happening.

Comment: yes, i see this now.  compare the output of `while true; do echo tick; done | tee >(grep -o ti) >(grep -o ic) | grep -o tick | uniq` and `while true; do echo tick; done | tee >(grep -o ti) >(grep -o ic) | grep tick | uniq`.  very interesting, thank you!