# Split and recombine stdout in Sh

Tags: bash, pipe, sh, stdout

I base the following question off [How can I split and re-join STDOUT from multiple processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23255841/2169092) .

The following Bash command splits the output of `command1` into two streams going into `command2` and `command3` before combining their outputs and piping it into `command4`.

```
((command1 | tee >(command2 >&3) | command3) 3>&1) | command4
```

Graphically this looks as follows:

```
         command2
        /        \
command1          command4
        \        /
         command3
```

How would i do this in the Sh shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In place of the process substitution use a fifo with a background process.

```
fifo=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo "$fifo"
{
    command2 <"$fifo" &
    command1 | tee "$fifo" | command3
    wait
} | command4
```

Example tested on busybox on alpine linux in docker:

```
f() { sed 's/^/'"$1"' /'; } ; 
fifo=$(mktemp -u); mkfifo "$fifo"; 
{ f 2 <"$fifo" & seq 3 | tee "$fifo" | f 3; wait; } | f 4;
rm "$fifo";
```

will output:

```
4 3 1
4 3 2
4 3 3
4 2 1
4 2 2
4 2 3
```