# Send process' STDOUT to screen and second process, but wait for both to finish

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, pipe

This is a sort of branch from this question (specifically avoiding the race condition pointed out by jmb): [How can I send the stdout of one process to multiple processes using (preferably unnamed) pipes in Unix (or Windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60942/how-can-i-send-the-stdout-of-one-process-to-multiple-processes-using-preferably)

I want to execute a process in such a way that its output is displayed on the screen plus piped to a second process, but that my terminal is not released until both processes are complete.  For example, if I had:

foo.sh

```
echo "FOO"
```

bar.sh:

```
read inp
sleep 5
echo "BAR${inp}BAR"
```

And then ran:

```
foo.sh | tee >(bar.sh)
```

I'd like to get the output:

```
FOO
BARFOOBAR
>           <--terminal released after bar (total time 5s)
```

but instead I get:

```
FOO
>BARFOOBAR  <--terminal released after foo in ~0s, before bar.sh returns at 5s
```

Is there an easy way to do this?  The only way I can think of right now is to instead call everything like this:

```
foo.sh | bar.sh
```

and then rewrite bar.sh such that it continually checks its STDIN and prints this to screen, but this seems like a very inelegant way of solving the problem.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
  foo.sh | tee /dev/tty | bar.sh
```

Comment: Should be noted that this solution is not specific to bash (i.e. portable).