# Is there a way to fanout a stream in posix shell or bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, posix, utility

I'd like something that works like:

```
cat a > b
prog1 < b
prog2 < b
```

without having to create the temporary b file.

If I just had one program, I could use a pipe:

```
cat a | prog1
```

I'm wondering if a shell has syntax to support something like:

```
cat a (|prog1) (|prog2)
```

Or is there a convenient utility that can help? Something like:

```
cat a | fanout prog1 prog2
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [tee](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tee) + [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) fork a stream of data and send it to multiple processes.

```
cat a | tee >(prog1) | prog2
```

`tee` takes file names as parameters. `>(prog1)` is replaced by a file name like `/dev/fd/63` that `tee` can write to.

To write to more than two programs, add more process substitutions:

```
cat a | tee >(prog1) >(prog2) >(prog3) | prog4
```

Comment: `tee >(prog1) >(prog2) >(prog3) < a | prog4` reduces extra pipe.

Comment: @codeforester: I think it's safe to assume that `cat a` is just an _example_ command, so in the general case you _do_ need a pipeline (or an _input_ process substitution).

Comment: You need to use `cat a | tee >(prog1) >(prog2) >/dev/null`, otherwise `prog1`'s output will _also_ be sent to `prog2` - try `echo hi | tee >(tr 'h' '@') | cat -n`.
Then, however, you get unpredictable, asynchronous output behavior, and the background processes may not have finished yet when the next command executes.
See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43906764/45375) of mine.