# How do I send btrfs snapshots to multiple destination drives?

Tags: backup, snapshot, btrfs

How do I make a BTRFS [incremental backup](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Incremental_Backup#Incremental_Operation) to multiple source destinations, so I don't have to run `btrfs send` multiple times?

```
btrfs send -p /tmp/parent_subvol /tmp/incremental_backup_snapshot | btrfs receive /mnt/destination_drive1
btrfs send -p /tmp/parent_subvol /tmp/incremental_backup_snapshot | btrfs receive /mnt/destination_drive2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in bash:

```
btrfs send -p /tmp/parent_subvol /tmp/incremental_backup_snapshot | tee >(btrfs receive /mnt/destination_drive2) | btrfs receive /mnt/destination_drive1
```

(courtesy [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60955/1429450))