# gzip: unexpected end of file when using gzip

Tags: linux, sh, gzip

I have to process a file using my Linux machine.

When I try to write my output to a csv file then gzip it in the same line of script:

`processing > output.csv | gzip -f output.csv`

I get an 'unexpected end of file' error. Even when I download the file using the Linux machine I get the same error.

When I do not gzip via terminal (or in a single line) everything works fine.

Why does it fail like this when the commands are all in a single line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `> output.csv`

You can either:

- Use a pipe: `|` or:
- Redirect to a file

For the same stream (stdout)

You can redirect errors from stderr to a file with `2>errors.txt` or they will display on screen

Comment: I need to use the processing output as well, so I needed a file in the gz archive.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean but maybe look at `tee` or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60942/how-can-i-send-the-stdout-of-one-process-to-multiple-processes-using-preferably

Answer (score 2):

When you redirect a process' IO with the `>` operator, its output cannot be used by a pipe afterwards (because there's no "output" anymore to be piped). You have two options:

1. ```
   processing > output.csv &&
   gzip output.csv
   ```

   Writes the unprocessed output of your program to the file `output.csv` and then in a second task gzips this file, replacing it with `output.gz`. Depending on the amount of data, this might not be feasible (storage reqirements are the full uncompressed output PLUS the compressed size)
2. ```
   processing | gzip > output.csv.gz
   ```

   This will compress the output of your process *in-line* and write it directly to the output file, without storing the uncompressed output in an intermediate file.