# Duplicate command output, print un-post-treated copy to stdout and store post-treated copy into a file

Tags: bash, unix, pipe, tee

I'm trying to duplicate a command's output so I apply a post-treatment to one stream, then store it to a file while printing the original one on stdout.

Closest I could come with is:

```
command | tee /dev/stdout | sed 's/foo/bar/g' > out.txt
```

which does not work as the `>` captures both outputs.

I'd like to avoid using a temporary file if possible. Any clue?

Comment: You could store the output in a bash variable with var=$(yor command)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I send the stdout of one process to multiple processes using (preferably unnamed) pipes in Unix (or Windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60942/how-can-i-send-the-stdout-of-one-process-to-multiple-processes-using-preferably)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
command | tee >(sed 's/foo/bar/g' > out.txt)
```

See [ProcessSubstitution - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) for an explanation of `>(...)`.  In short, it causes `tee` to write to a path that pipes the written data as input to the `sed 's/foo/bar/g' > out.txt` command.

Comment: Brilliant! 10 years in programming and never used process substitution...